# TCL onliner: replace string in filename

Tags: replace, tcl

Is there a way to replace strings in filenames with oneliner using TCL. For example, with perl it would be:

files:

```
testA1.txt
testA2.txt
testA3.txt
```

Oneliner

```
perl -e "while(<test*>) {($new=$_) =~ s/A/B/; rename $_, $new}"
```

Files

```
testB1.txt
testB2.txt
testB3.txt
```

In generally, is TCL appropriate for oneliners? I didn't find in the net oneliners for TCL as I found for Perl and Powershell.

OS: Windows 7

Comment: It's pretty rare that anyone's encouraged to write one-liners in Tcl; as a community, we tend to emphasise making code to last instead of using the minimum number of characters possible.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest I can think of would be this:

```
foreach f [glob test*] {file rename $f [string map {A B} $f]}
```

Like in any language though, one liners are generally for quick and dirty things or for fun. Not something you'd find in proper code.

Comment: Thanks. But how I have to add it on the dos-terminal? I tried `>tclsh foreach f [glob test*] {file rename $f [string map {A B} $f]}`. But this does not work.

Comment: This is why tcl's not great for oneliners: you have to do feed the code into tclsh's stdin: `echo 'foreach f [glob test*] {file rename $f [string map {A B} $f]} | tclsh`

Comment: A decade ago (!) [I wrote a tcl script to provide perl-like command line options](http://wiki.tcl.tk/17599), but it never caught on. I really never used it either.

Comment: @glenn Thanks for help and the link. Since I can't install Perl on our PC due to restriction but TCL (why?) maybe I will use tcl.tcl once.

Comment: Oops, missing single quote in my first comment. I did not close the quoted string for echo.

Comment: That is a strange restriction. One would think Perl is more widely viewed as "standard software" than Tcl. But if you have Tcl, go install [tcllib](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/toc.html)

Comment: On Windows 7 it doesn't work with single and double quote. Without quotes it works. Perl/TCL: In windows word both are not standard software. Our institution is a hospital and has very strong restrictions. But it is strange: Perl and Python asks for administration rights, TCL and Ruby not. I don't understand that. Thanks for your link to tclib. I just started with tcl to build a frontend with sqlite as alternative to MS Access.

Comment: @giordano ah sorry for my lack of responsiveness I could not come online the past few days

Comment: @giordano You can install ActivePerl without admin, see http://docs.activestate.com/activeperl/5.8/install.html

Comment: @giordano Windows' echo builtin is pretty limited and does not follow the same quoting rules as the rest of the command interpreter. For example `echo ""` outputs the literal string `""` but writing `tclsh "foo\"bar"` passes the string `foo"bar` to tclsh as one argument. It is not possible to echo a `|` character and pipe that into a program with the Windows echo builtin.